# OnTriggerStay2D Collide on a specific object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, void

```
    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (Beam.state == 2)
        {
            DMG += 1f;
        }
    }
```

And I need it to only trigger when touching The Beam named object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity how to check what object triggered a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998673/unity-how-to-check-what-object-triggered-a-trigger)

Comment: what `specific object`? You can filter on everything the `other` provides ... `.tag`, `.layer`, `.name` ... the exact `.gameObject` reference or a certain component on it ...

Comment: you can also filter on script, using GetComponent and checking if the result is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

On your object, add a tag, name it something appropriate, and then assign it to the object. Change your code to this:

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "YOURTAGNAME") // Check if the collided gameobject has the unique tag you assigned to that "beam" gameobject
    {
        if (Beam.state == 2)
        {
            DMG += 1f;
        }
    }
}
```